# Сильные/слабые позиция для глухих и звонких согласных

Tags: фонетика, фонология

Являются ли сочетания двух звонких/глухих согласных звуков подряд орфограммой? Т.е. в какой позиции они находятся - в сильной или слабой?

Пример: **зд**ание, гру**зд**и, опу**шк**а.

В интернете толком ничего не удалось найти. Только на одном сайте (сайт учителя русского языка) говорится следующее:  для парных звонких согласных **сильная позиция** —  перед звонкими согласными: здание [зданий’э];
**для парных  глухих — перед глухими согласными:** миска [миска].

Просьба давать ответы с ссылкой на учебник.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Здание — слабая позиция З перед шумным Д, грузди — слабая позиция З перед шумным Д, опушка — слабая позиция Ш перед шумным К. Буквы в этих позициях теоретически  являются орфограммами, то есть требуют проверки на письме (они произносятся одинаково с последующим шумным согласным  — глухо или звонко).

Слабыми по звонкости-глухости являются позиции ПАРНЫХ согласных Б/П, В/Ф, Г/К, Д/Т, З/С, Ж/Ш  перед шумными согласными (несонорными). Сильными позициями являются позиции парных согласных перед гласными, сонорными (Л, М, Н, Р). Некоторые особенности есть у звука В.

http://www.studfiles.ru/preview/5958391/

Дополнение

С другой стороны, реально эти слова никто не проверяет, и вот очень интересно почему. Причина, скорее всего, в том, что разные по звонкости-глухости согласные обычно встречаются на стыке морфем, сравнить: опушка (опушить), сторожка (сторожить). В начале и середине корня согласные обычно одинаковые (здание, грузди), так как одинаковое произношение в конце концов отражается на письме. Например, др.-рус. "истьба" стала избой.

Answer (score 2):

Что такое сильная или слабая позиции в орфографии, не понятно, но, кажется, имеется в виду это: сильная позиция не вызывает вопросов при написании, слабая — вызывает. Если так, то выделенные вами звуки находятся в "сильной позиции" и не вызывают вопросов при написании (не являются орфограммой).

Дело в том, что глухие/звонкие идущие подряд звуки не оглушаются и не озвончаются, "слышатся, как пишутся", поэтому не вызывают трудности при написании. Сравните: здесь [з' д' э с'] — вопросов нет, звуки и буквы "совпадают", и а**с**бест [а **з** б' э с т] — слышится *з*, а пишется *с* (этот случай считается орфограммой "непроверяемый согласный в корне").

Список орфограмм вы можете посмотреть, например, здесь: https://grammatika-rus.ru/glavnaya/orfograficheskij-razbor/spisok-orfogramm/.